# rviz segfault core dumped (tried all OGRE_RTT_MODEs)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS fuerte on ubuntu 12.04.2LTS
I was running rviz happily until I did an apt-get update/upgrade.
Many ROS packages have been updated, then when I run rviz I get the following error:

micmac@xubuntu:~$ rosrun rviz rviz -d /home/micmac/fuerte_workspace/neato_robot/XV11-Kinect.vcg
[ INFO] [1362475463.736896709]: rviz revision number 1.8.17
[ INFO] [1362475463.737052628]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1362475463.851547794]: Loading display config from []
[ INFO] [1362475463.851693479]: Loading general config from [/home/micmac/.rviz/config]
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)

I tried to set OGRE_RTT_MODE (export) to all supported modes, without success.
Still segfault.

Could you please help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57077/rviz-segfault-core-dumped-(tried-all-ogre_rtt_modes)/) by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-03-05**:
You could try to delete RViz's temporary folder in ~/.rviz
I'm not sure though if this could help.

**Comment by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) on 2013-03-05**:
I have tried to delete the ~/.rviz folder completely, but same error (segfault). The ~/.rviz folder is re-created but rviz still crashes. I also have to say that it crashes even with no config file specified ("rosrun rviz rviz" alone).

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-03-05**:
You can try to update/reinstall your graphic drivers.
If that doesn't help, try to build from the source.

Are there any other nodes running when you start RViz?

**Comment by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) on 2013-03-05**:
Okay i'll try to update graphic drivers. There is not other node running when starting RViz.

**Comment by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) on 2013-03-05**:
Updating to the latest graphic drivers revision (nvidia) solved the issue ! Thanks !!

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-03-05**:
You're welcome. I'll post this as an official answer, would be happy if you could mark it as correct then.

**Comment by [Harvey](https://answers.ros.org/users/38036/harvey/) on 2018-10-14**:
Hi miacmac:
I have met the same issue as you mentioned. Could you please tell me how to update graphic drivers?? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some apt-get updates you will have to update the graphic drivers.
If that doesn't help have a look at the RViz trouble shooting:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting

---

Originally posted by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) with karma: 230 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1